# Riot.js: mounting tags with same variable

Tags: riot.js

I have 3 customs tags: `my-tag1`, `my-tag2` and `my-tag3`

And I am using them like this:

```
<my-tag1>
  <my-tag2 attr1="a">
    <my-tag3 attr2="b"></my-tag3>
  </my-tag2>
</my-tag1>
```

I am mounting all tags like this:

```
riot.mount('*', { store:reduxStore });
```

`my-tag1` can access to `store` but `my-tag2`and `my-tag3` can not do it.

However, if I do the following, `my-tag2` can use `store`:

```
<my-tag1>
  <my-tag2 attr1="a" store={opts.store}>
    <my-tag3 attr2="b"></my-tag3>
  </my-tag2>
</my-tag1>
```

Why? I have to do that in all my tags?

Answer (score 0):

`riot.mount('*')` mounts all top-level tags. The top-level tags take care of mounting their sub-tags respectively
If you want to pass a store, I think it is best to use mixins. See http://riotjs.com/guide/#mixins

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When tags are nested, a new context is created
for a child tag.  In the new context, all the parent's properties
inherited are set to `undefined`.

References:

- https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/1720
- http://riotjs.com/guide/#context

In your example, by adding `store={opts.store}` in `my-tag2`, you are
defining an option `store` in `my-tag2`'s new context.  If you don't do
that, the option `store` in `my-tag2`'s context is inherited from
`my-tag1`, but it is set to `undefined` (so `my-tag2` sees `undefined` for
the `store`'s value).

In order to share the `store`'s value across `my-tag1`, `my-tag2`, and `my-tag3`,
there are two ways in my opinion:

1) `my-tag3` initializes `store`'s value to `my-tag2`'s `store`

```
<my-tag1>
  <my-tag2 attr1="a" store={opts.store}>
    <my-tag3 attr2="b" store={opts.store}></my-tag3>
  </my-tag2>
</my-tag1>
```

2) `my-tag3` initializes `store`'s value to `my-tag1`'s `store` using the
   `parent` variable.

```
<my-tag1>
  <my-tag2 attr1="a" store={opts.store}>
    <my-tag3 attr2="b" store={parent.opts.store}></my-tag3>
  </my-tag2>
</my-tag1>
```